# How to refresh page automatically if it fails to load(get(url)) after waiting for a certain amount of time using Selenium

Tags: java

I have a web-page, which launches fine every time when I launch it normally. But when I launch it using selenium webdriver(by get and navigate().to()) methods, it loads only  say 5 out of 10 times. For the rest of the time, it keeps loading forever. However, when I refresh it several times, it gets loaded.

I have tried using selenium waits, but they don't solve my problem.

Comment: What is the error thrown when the page keeps loading forever?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at such forum: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2606/what-is-seleniums-default-timeout-for-page-loading

SOLUTION: In the code, before the line with 'get' method you can use for example:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

One thing is that it throws timeoutException so you have to encapsulate it in the try catch block or wrap in some method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **pageLoadStrategy = none**;
and try if an element is present and refresh if not.

An example for Chrome:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

options.setCapability("pageLoadStrategy", "none");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

driver.get(url);

while(true){ //this can be infinite loop.

    try{

        Thread.sleep(milisecs);//how much to wait for element.
        driver.findElement(element);  
        //You can use ExplicitWait for elegant code.

        break;

    }catch(Exception e){

        driver.navigate().refresh();

    }
}
```